# i want to know can i connect two pc wirthout any wire or internet for socket server programming

Tags: sockets

I am very confused. I cannot find a specific answer to my question.I'm writing my application in core Java specifically.

So, I am simply trying to connect two separate computers.
Computer 'A' is the server, and Computer 'B' is the client.

When the Client connects to the server. This code is about client and server communication in java. I can run both codes in my PC and can connect client and server. But how will I connect 2 computers as a client and server.

Question: I just want to know that can I connect two PC without internet or wireless connection to run this code as a  server and client on two different PC.
Can I use ad Hoc network?
Here are my codes for server and client as follows:

```
MyServer1
{
try
    {
        System.out.println("Server Started");
        ss=new ServerSocket(10);
        s=ss.accept();
        System.out.println(s);
        System.out.println("CLIENT CONNECTED");
        dis= new DataInputStream(s.getInputStream());
        dos= new DataOutputStream(s.getOutputStream());
        ServerChat();
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
         System.out.println(e);
    }
}

public static void main (String as[])
{
     new MyServer1();
}

public void ServerChat() throws IOException
{
     String str, s1;
     do
     {
         str=dis.readUTF();
         System.out.println("Client Message:"+str);
         BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader(new   InputStreamReader(System.in));
         s1=br.readLine();
         dos.writeUTF(s1);
         dos.flush();
     }
     while(!s1.equals("bye"));
}



MyClient1

//code for client
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;

public class MyClient1
{
Socket s;
DataInputStream din;
DataOutputStream dout;
public MyClient1()
{
     try
     {
         //s=new Socket("10.10.0.3,10");
         s=new Socket("MyServere1",10);
         System.out.println(s);
         din= new DataInputStream(s.getInputStream());
         dout= new DataOutputStream(s.getOutputStream());
         ClientChat();
     }
     catch(Exception e)
     {
         System.out.println(e);
     }
 }
 public void ClientChat() throws IOException
 {
BufferedReader br= new BufferedReader(newInputStreamReader(System.in));        
       String s1;
       do
       {
           s1=br.readLine();
           dout.writeUTF(s1);
           dout.flush();
           System.out.println("Server Message:"+din.readUTF());
       }
       while(!s1.equals("stop"));
}
```

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is asking for networking advice - nothing to do with software development at all.

Comment: Please explain what layer 1 you expect to use, (ie. how you plan to get bits from one box to the other), with no cables or wireless interface?

Answer (score 0):

As long as both computers are on the same network, whether its a peer to peer, LAN or a much wider network, you should be able to. The key is this, if you ping one machine from the other, do you get a hit if yes then they should connect, if not then they won't

**CAVEAT**: I have not looked at your code and I don't think this question has much to do with programming, it is probably more suited to networking.